# Unable to receive any messages in Kafka 0.10.0 with Spark stream 1.6.2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Recently we moved to HDP 2.5 which has Kafka 0.10.0 and Spark 1.6.2. So I modified my pom and some of the APIs to work with new Kafka. I can run the code but I do not see any messages coming in. I have added a code snippet below. I have also posted my pom. I am not sure what is going wrong here. Can someone please help.

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName(
        "SparkApp");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf,
        Durations.seconds(2));      

Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
topicMap.put(this.topic, this.numThreads);

Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", kfkBroker);
kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", zkBroker);
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "default");
kafkaParams.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", "60000000");                

JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> kafkaInStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(
    jssc,
    String.class,
    String.class,
    kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.class,
    kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.class,
    kafkaParams,
    topicMap,
    StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());

    kafkaInStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String, String>>()
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> v1) throws Exception
    {

        System.out.println("inside call.. JavaPairRDD size  " + v1.count());
        for (Tuple2<String, String> test : v1.collect())
        {
            this.eventMessage.setMessage(test._2);
        }

    }

});
```

I get an output "inside call.. JavaPairRDD size  0" always which indicates that spark is not reading any data. I tried pushing some data into the topic through console consumer.But that did not help.

Here is my pom.xml (only dependencies added)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark-streaming-kafka_2.10` only works with Kafka 0.8+ client. You can still use Kafka 0.8+ client to connect to a 0.10+ cluster but loss some performance.

I suggest that you just use `--packages` to submit your application to avoid setting Kafka in your dependencies. E.g.,

```
bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2 ...
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the recommended version for Kafka 0.10 and spark 1.6.2? Maven repository shows 1.6.2 for spark streaming.

Comment: You don't need to add Kafka client to your pom.xml. `spark-streaming-kafka_2.10` already depends on it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. May be my question wasn't right. What version of spark streaming Kafka should I use in my project for my Kafka 0.10 and spark 1.6.2?

Comment: There is only one version you can use: spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 1.6.2

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Please let me know the reason why my code is not working. It  is unable to capture any messages. Is my KafkaUtils.createStream right one?

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted. What I did is to include the old Kafka version in my pom xml. I was able to receive messages.

Comment: That's fine. But I was saying that you don't need to do that because that's a transitive dependency of spark-streaming-kafka_2.10.